# Heroku pushing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

when I run my app on heroku all I get is this

```
Heroku | Welcome to your new app!
Refer to the documentation if you need help deploying.
```

so I tried to push my app to heroku using this command

```
git push heroku master
```

I get this error: **error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'heroku'**

any solutions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Git Repository does not have a `ref` named `heroku`. 
Try following [this post](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs).